# Existence of a set $C$ such that $|B|=|C|$ and $A\cap C=\emptyset$

Tags: set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets.

Is there a set $C$ such that $|B|=|C|$ and $A\cap C=\emptyset$?

Comment: So, you're wondering if $A, B$ are fixed sets, can we always find a set $C$ with the same cardinality as $B$, that is disjoint from $C$? Try $C = B \times \{A\}$.

Comment: The answer depends on what your universal set is.

Comment: @TheoBendit How do you prove that there is no element $b \in B$ that satisfies $(b, A)\in A$?

Comment: @Ponta That depends on your axioms, but allowing such a set would violate, for instance, ZF. The transitive closure of such an $A$ would violate the axiom of foundation.

Comment: @Ponta Note that an ordered pair $(b,A)$ is defined as $\{b,\{b,A\}\}$